# ¿Como comparar y validar fechas en JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo `javascript` necesito comparar y validar fechas este es mi ejemplo completo.

Aquí está el ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer es pasar un resultado de un campo de texto a otro pero no me funciona.

```js
function dateAgo(date) {
    var startDate = new Date(date);
    var diffDate = new Date(new Date() - startDate);
    return ((diffDate.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970) + "-" + diffDate.getMonth() + "-" + (diffDate.getDate() - 1));
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Fechas</h1>
        <input type="text" name="startDate"id="startDate" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="diffDate"id="diffDate" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="dateAgo" id="dateAgo" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas usando Javascript nativo o JQuery?

Comment: si estoy usando jQuery Nativo no me esta funcionando el ejemplo

Comment: Tienes muchas opciones, pero te recomiendo usar alguna librería especializada en esto. A mí me gusta [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/); es ligera y tiene una API muy completa.

Comment: @ALDO56 cual es el resultado que esperas? la diferencia entre las dos fechas en días?

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: espera un numero entero con la diferencia entre dos fechas

Comment: Para ser sincero, no se entiende el detalle de lo que requieres, primero mencionas que necesitas comparar dos fechas y luego que necesitas pasar un valor de una caja de texto a otra. Por favor, redacta bien para poder ayudarte.

Comment: si necesito comparar dos fechas y pasar el resultado a un campo de texto o un div pero no logro obtener resultados los valores que espera el sript deben ser tomados de las cajas de textos y pasar el resultado a otro ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Con la libreria moment.js resuelves todo de manera más sencilla.

Comment: no veo donde introduces el parametro de entrada

Answer (score 1):

Primero, te invito a que averigües un poco más sobre la forma de trabajar los elementos del `DOM`, y los eventos de `JavaScript` ya que debes enlazar los elementos a éstos para que funcionen.

Fuera de eso, acá te dejo la solución en JavaScript

```js
function calcular() {
  const start = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value)
  const end = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value)
  const diffTime = end.getTime() - start.getTime()
  const diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24) 
  alert(`${diffDays} días`)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-2">
  <input type="date" id="start">
  <input type="date" id="end">
  <input type="submit" onclick="calcular()">
</div>
```

De todas maneras te insto a usar la librería de **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)**, que tiene infinidad de funcionalidades que te facilitarán el trabajo relacionado a fechas.

Y **[acá](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)** una guía de los eventos de `JavaScript`.

Nos comentas como te va

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda voy a probar el codigo